# Spring Boot controller to handle invalid JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have a Spring Boot controller that consumes JSON:

```
    @PostMapping(
    value = "/shipdetails")
    public ResponseEntity acceptShip(@RequestBody Ship ship, HttpServletRequest request) {
        shipService.checkShip(ship);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

There is a corresponding Ship Entity:

```
public class Ship implements Serializable {

@JsonProperty("Name")
private String name;
@JsonProperty("Owner")
private String owner;

public Ship(String name, String owner) {
    this.name = name;
    this.owner = owner;    }

public Ship() {
}

// Getters and Setters removed for brevity
```

And finally the service:

```
@Service
public class ShipService {

Boolean checkShip(Ship ship) {
    if (ship.getName().equals("Queen Mary")) {
         // do something
    }
//edited for brevity
```

Sample invalid JSON:

```
{
    "name_wrong":"test name",
    "owner":"Lloyds Shipping"
}
```

Currently the error I get on the stacktrace if I send invalid JSON is (service layer) : `Cannot invoke "String.equals(Object)" because the return value of "com.ships.Ship.getName()" is null`.

Jackson needs the no-args constructor for de-serialization.

When inspecting in the debugger the Ship entity has a owner set, but not a name set, so its not the the whole entity is null - just one field.

I tried my Ship entity without a default no args constructor so you could not even pass entity with a null field to the service but then it fails with even valid JSON.

How and where should the exception for invalid JSON be handled?

Comment: Test the return value for null first before attempting to use it?

Comment: On a entity with lots of fields this could take a long time. Can you be more specific? The whole entity is not invalid, but it fails to set the field with the wrong name.

Comment: If the JSON is well-formed but is missing data, you need to verify that the correct data is present.  Otherwise you will get an exception wherever you reference missing data, which could be anywhere in your code.  You don't even know in advance _which_ possible exceptions could be thrown.  You must either check for data validity at load time, or wherever you _use_ the data (actually, in _both_ places for code robustness).  There is no easy shortcut.  Coding is easy -- writing real software is hard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Need to add few annotations and checks for the validation of the request body json.

**1. Add dependency in pom.xml for the below annotations-**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**2. @Valid with Request Body**

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/shipdetails")
    public ResponseEntity acceptShip(@Valid @RequestBody Ship ship, 
                                     HttpServletRequest request)
```

**3. @NotNull with the mandatory attributes**

```
    public class Ship implements Serializable {

      @NotNull(message = "The name is mandatory")
      @JsonProperty("Name")
      private String name;
      @JsonProperty("Owner")
      private String owner;
```

**4. Additional null check before equals method**

```
Boolean checkShip(Ship ship) {
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(ship.getName()) 
            && ship.getName().equals("Queen Mary")) {
            // do something
        }
```

**Output with Invalid json:**

**Input**

```
    {
     "name_wrong":"test name",
     "owner":"Lloyds Shipping"
    }
```

**Output:**
You will get a 400 Bad request status with the long error stack trace includes something like this

```
    "message": "Validation failed for object='ship'. Error count: 1",
"errors": [
    {
        "codes": [
            "NotNull.ship.name",
            "NotNull.name",
            "NotNull.java.lang.String",
            "NotNull"
        ],
        "arguments": [
            {
                "codes": [
                    "ship.name",
                    "name"
                ],
                "arguments": null,
                "defaultMessage": "name",
                "code": "name"
            }
        ],
        "defaultMessage": "The name is mandatory",
        "objectName": "ship",
        "field": "name",
        "rejectedValue": null,
        "bindingFailure": false,
        "code": "NotNull"
    }
]
```

**Note:**
Some Additional code for handling the **`MethodArgumentNotValidException`** exception using our custom exceptionHandler so that the validation will be in a proper formatted response instead of lengthly error stacktrace and control the status code as well as shown below:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ValidationExceptionHandler {
    /**
     * For an invalid input, spring framework will throw an 
            MethodArgumentNotValidException exception
     */
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> notValidInput(MethodArgumentNotValidException e) {
        Map<String,String> errorMap = e.getAllErrors()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> ((FieldError)x).getField(), 
                 b -> b.getDefaultMessage(),(p,q) -> p, LinkedHashMap::new));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorMap, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

**Formatted output for invalid json:**

```
{
    "name": "The name is mandatory"
}
```

Comment: this answer seems pretty sound and I will mark as accepted. It would be gold standard to have some info on valid bean in the controller.

Comment: Does the controller response then need a if block to change between HttpStatus.OK and the 400?

Comment: I did some tests. So the valid bean ensures compliance with the NotNull bean - but does not stop execution if another field has a wrong name for example owners instead of owner - unless I made owner also notnull but that seems a hacky way to ensure the field name is correct.

Comment: @RadikaMoonesinghe For an invalid input, spring framework will throw an ```MethodArgumentNotValidException``` exception with a status code ```400``` and you can handle it by creating a ```@ExceptionHandler``` using a ```@ControllerAdvice```.

Comment: @RadikaMoonesinghe yes, ```@Valid``` will validate only those fields which are annotated like with ```@NotNull``` or ```@NotBlank``` and so on..

Comment: Got it. And beyond valid bean is it normal to just let Jackson ignore incorrect field names and map what it can (vs. trying to strictly enforce 100% correctly formatted json)

Comment: @RadikaMoonesinghe Yes, right, additionally, I have included the code for exception handler as well to get the validation error(s) in a proper formatted response.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than viewing the issue as being a misnamed field, think of it as instead being two issues: a missing property (`name`) and an extra property (`name_wrong`).

Spring Boot is configured by default to ignore any extra properties.  And unless you tell the controller that the `name` property is required (e.g. by using the `@NotNull` bean validation annotation on the `name` field), it will happily accept a null value for this property.

## Missing required property

The `NullPointerException` is happening since you're attempting to call `equals` on the `null` `name` field.

```
ship.getName().equals("Queen Mary")
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

There are a few different fixes for this.  First, you could add a bean validation to the required fields:

```java
public class Ship implements Serializable {
  @NotNull
  @JsonProperty("Name")
  private String name;

  @JsonProperty("Owner")
  private String owner;

  // ...
}
```

Alternatively, you could change the equals method to be null-safe:

```java
Boolean checkShip(Ship ship) {
    if (Objects.equals(ship.getName(), "Queen Mary"))) {
         // do something
    }
}
```

## Extra property

There are several ways to have Spring reject the extra `name_wrong` property.

If you want the application to always reject unknown properties (unless a particular bean opts out of it), you can configure it globally:

**`application.yml`**

```yml
spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties: false
```